# What is the meaning of AFAIK abbreviation?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, expressions, abbreviations

I would like to understand what is the meaning of AFAIK, as used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25501190/2989289) at StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for As Far As I Know.

> AFAIK
>   in British English
>   messaging & social media
>   ABBREVIATION FOR
>   as far as I know

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/afaik